# What is the policy for linking to your own blog in your answers?

Tags: discussion

What is the policy for linking to your own guides, articles,  blogs or tutorials in your answers?

Also let's say you write an article explaining how to solve a novel problem. Then you do a search and see that many questions (at least 5 or more) are regarding this problem and that they have not been answered.

Are you allowed to go through every question and link to your article as long as you address the specific unique needs and concerns of the asker in every case?  Is it spam if the answer addresses the questioner and answers the question better than other answers even if you answer and link to yourself many times in a short period of time?

Comment: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209031/gitk-installation-is-not-working-on-linux/71345391#71345391).

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element/70986923#70986923).

Comment: [Yet another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687618/local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-google-android-gms-providerinstaller-dynam/76809602#76809602).

Answer (score 16):

This has been covered before, although those questions & answers are now on Meta.SE. You could try starting here: [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers). Another good resource is [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)

> What is the policy for linking to your own guides, articles, blogs or tutorials in your answers?

In general it's okay provided you are totally open,  you have full disclosure. You should include a relevant section from your target article that addresses the question, so that the link is secondary and people don't need to leave the site for the answer.

> Are you allowed to go through every question and link to your article as long as you address the specific unique needs and concerns of the asker in every case?

People will quickly get grouchy about it if you start putting your links everywhere - make sure you individually answer each question, don't just use a cookie-cutter or template answer (I've flagged people for this in the past).

If you provide a quality answer people will not mind that you've linked to additional information on your blog.