# What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260524/how-should-i-have-handled-what-looked-like-spam-answers) question deals with denied spam flags.

The following example of a low-quality answer with a link to an external site is given in the question:

> We can find the permutation of a string by using recursion.
>
> - Take the first character of the input string.
> - Permute all the characters in the remainder of the string recursively and create a new array with them.
> - Add the first character into each possible position of the new array and return.
>
> For example and code http //www.algoqueue.com/algoqueue/default/view/6684672/print-permutation-of-a-string

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work) is I think the currently accepted definition for spam:

> What makes something spam and when should I flag it?
>
> A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an unsolicited
> advertisement.
>
> It should NOT be marked as spam when:
>
> The answer contains no useful information, such as an answer that says
> "I don't care about your problem". Flag an answer as 'not an answer'
> instead; if you find a weird non-question, then flag it 'for moderator
> attention' with a custom explanation.

How is the shown example, which is a very low-quality answer with a link to another site, not considered spam? (Particularly since this is a recurring theme for the poster.) To me that's clearly "unsolicited advertisement" just with a little spin to make it less obvious and obnoxious.

As Cupcake emphasizes: The problem isn't so much a user doing this once or twice, but this being a **recurring** theme for a user. Taking the behavior of the user into account, I really think this should be considered spam, flagged and treated as such with the negative consequences for the user.

Comment: I think taking a look at that particular user's broader behavior is even more telling. [22 ***really crappy*** answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/350129/neel?tab=answers) posted between June 5th to June 13th, ***all containing a link back to AlgoQueue.com***. I'd call that a mass spam ***campaign***.

Comment: @Cupcake Agreed, very good comment. I did mention it on the side, but I should make it more prominent. Clearly someone once posting a link to a site is different (I don't really have a problem with that) than someone doing so repeatedly always for the same site.

Comment: @Cupcake I normally use my personal website for PHP/HTML/CSS/Javascript/etc experiments and some times reference a particular experiment for showing the problem (when porting it to jsfiddle would be too costly or not possible), so careful with this one.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

### What is Spam?

Spam is **unsolicited advertisement or promotion, *or* recommending, linking, etc. something to which you are affiliated without disclosing that affiliation in your post** (with some exceptions<sup>1</sup>).  We've all seen it, and we all know what it looks like.  It looks like the same stuff you see in your spam folder when you look at your email.

#### Example of Spam

> From: Ms. Carman L. Lapointe.
> UNITED NATIONS OFFICE OF INTERNATIONAL OVERSIGHT SERVICES
>
> Right now, as directed by our secretary general Mr.Ban Ki-Moon, We
> have agreed with the Nigeria Government that US$100,000.00 (One
> Hundred Thousand United States Dollars Only) would be paid to you
> through the Western Union Money Transfer Via special arrangement
> as first installment.
>
> I await your response for further proceedings.
>
> Sincerely yours,
> Ms. Carman L. Lapointe
> {Under-Secretary-General} United Nations

### What is Excessive/Improper Promotion?

Excessive promotion is a bit different than spam.  Excessive promotion occurs when a user answers the question, but then puts a link to their blog or website in their answer with or without disclosing that they are linking to their own website in multiple answers. How many is usually judgement call moderators make based on the volume of the posts promoting the user's thing compared to their other contributions, both overall and around the time that the excessive promotion is posted.

#### Example of Excessive/Improper Promotion

> - Take an empty integer array of 256 elements to hold the frequency of character of the string.
> - Iterate through the string and construct the frequency array.
> - Increment the current value of the frequency array by 1 at the location of the corresponding ASCII value of the character.
> - Iterate through the string and check the frequency array.
> - Return the first element whose frequency is 1.
>
> For explanation and code
> http://www.algoqueue.com/algoqueue/default/view/6881280/first-non-repeating-character-in-a-string

This answer is improper, because the author did not disclose their affiliation with the website to which they linked, and the code is at the link, instead of posted here.

### Are users allowed to promote their website in an answer?

In general, if links are included in an answer to a question, they must meet *[all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/102937)* [of the following guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/102937) (with thanks to Kate Gregory):

- you paraphrase the content of the linked item (possibly omitting details or examples)
- you identify the author (yourself, MSDN, etc)
- someone could benefit from the answer without reading the linked item at all
- you include information to let the reader decide if clicking the link is worthwhile

For example:

> You can use the CircularLabelsStyle
> custom property for this, for example:
>
> ```
>   chart1.Series["Series1"]["CircularLabelsStyle"] = "Circular";
> ```
>
> I [blogged about this last year](http://example.com), with
> some sample code.

### How do I report excessive or improper promotion?

To have a user reviewed for *excessive promotion,* flag one of their answers using a custom moderator flag, and explain the problem.

The message that a user receives when a mod message is sent or a suspension is imposed for excessive promotion is this:

> We noticed that a substantial proportion of your posts seem to exist
> only to promote your product or website. Per the help center:
>
> > *Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and*
> > tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant
> > answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or
> > website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your
> > answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of
> > your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.
> > Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team
> > for details.
>
> Any type of "astroturfing" promotion is not acceptable. It brings down
> the overall value of genuine recommendations for everyone on the site.
>
> If you can stay within the above guidelines, and offer questions and
> answers of genuine benefit to the community which happen to mention
> your affiliation or product in context -- and with full disclosure --
> then your future contributions are welcome.

### Spam is treated differently

If an account is identified as a spammer account, and one of their spam posts is deleted via six community spam flags, a 100 reputation penalty is imposed.  This will earn a spammer account a question ban fairly quickly.

The accounts of drive-by spammers are summarily deleted, and their account information is placed into the Stack Exchange Spammer Detector to help identify them if they come back.

---

1. You do not need to disclose your affiliation when:

   - the question is by an unaffiliated user (i.e., isn't astroturfing) and is *specifically* about your thing;
   - you link only to official documenation or other official resources directly relevant to the answer/question;
   - your post actually answers the question; *and*
   - your post doesn't read like an advertisement.

Comment: Related post from a user who was asking about how to go about linking to his own blog: [What is the policy for linking to your own blog in your answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254280/456814).

Comment: Thanks.  The answer posted there is very similar to the one Kate Gregory gave on the Stack Exchange question I linked.

Comment: When I'm in a [java] mood, a significant fraction of my answers contain links to docs.oracle.com. See the next to last paragraph of http://stackoverflow.com/a/24225388/1798593 for an example. Do I need to put in more explanation of the links, such as identifying the author, as recommended in the second bullet point, or is just mentioning the JLS good enough in context?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: The answer you linked can stand on its own without the supporting links to the Oracle website.  That's how you can tell that the answer is not primarily promotional.  It's very clear that you're linking to the documentation for Java to supplement an already good answer.

Comment: This answer just goes to show (one of the reasons) why I shouldn't be a moderator `:/`.

Comment: @Cupcake: Really, it's not all that difficult to figure out. Y'all do the same thing with the Not an Answer flag; you overthink it.  If it looks like one and smells like one, it probably is.

Comment: I am questioning the effectiveness of the Kate Gregory guidelines, included in this article, for distinguishing legitimate use of links. If you look at the totality of the answer I referenced above, it is a non-promotional answer supported by references to the relevant standard. If you mechanically apply the guideline tests, I neither stated the author nor paraphrased the content of the links. I think doing either would have reduced the quality of the answer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: We are humans here, not computers. Moderators especially (and any member doing anything) are required to exercise their common sense when applying any guideline. Remember the golden rule: Whatever makes the site better is the proper action, even if it goes against some guideline.

Comment: That's definitely an excellent FAQ post. I would also point out that meta.SO should also make it more clear that "spam" flags also shouldn't be used for people posting just complete "I'm clearly bored" gibberish, either. Because flagging for "spam" *does* often extend to including things like "LOLLOLLOLASDF!!!asouidhfasuiohrre" in many other web communities. Should be made clear that that crap should just get "not an answer" flagged.

Comment: I suggest adding "The link is relevant to the content"  to the list of criteria.

Comment: The focus exclusively on commercial solicitations is misdirected. Classical corner cases you would like to include are e.g. chain letters (or more generally social engineering schemes), religious and scientific promotions (there's a regular crank on Maths.SE if you are looking for a concrete example), [survey invitations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175007/are-questionnaires-permitted-on-stack-exchange-sites), etc.

Comment: Historically, the reason US email anti-spam advocates have focused on outlawing UCE over UBE is that "commercial speech" is easier to regulate without hitting pesky interpretation questions about the First Amendment to the US Constition, but as a site operator, disallowing posts of certain kinds on the server you run is exempt anyway, even if you are in the US. ("*Congress* shall make no law ...", emphasis mine.)

Comment: @tripleee Just for the record: the *first amendment* is about preventing the **government** from suppressing dissenting voices. It does not **apply** when a *private* organization/community defines the rules for its **own** stuff. When somebody enters your how, and starts screaming something you dont want to hear - it is perfectly fine to show him the way out - without violating that first amendment. Within your own realms, you are free censor or not censor as it pleases you.

Comment: @GhostCat That's precisely what I was saying, yes. The reason *some* spam definitions include "commercial" is because they are a vehicle for promoting a law in the United States against (commercial) spam, but if that's not your goal, focusing on commercial promotions exclusively is not required or justified.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Could you explain how "put[ting] a link to their blog or website in their answer without disclosing that they are linking to their own website" constitutes *excessive* promotion?

Comment: @pushkin: It doesn't constitute *excessive* promotion, if you're just talking about one answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah, so "excessive" here means the user makes several posts linking to himself. Not that his *one* post excessively self-promotes.

Comment: So just to reiterate, can we take out "commercial" from this definition? As an excellent case in point, the example is actually not commercial in nature.

Comment: @tripleee: It's not my example, but "commercial" is close enough.  "Commercial" is there to distinguish from other messages commonly called spam that are not actually spam.

Comment: Do you disagree that indiscriminately posting off-topic promotions for e.g. noncommercial web sites (mathematical cranks with proofs they want to promote, religious propaganda, social media awareness campaigns, political pontification, etc) are also spam? We see nontrivial amounts of all of these (though some of them are probably shady commercial tactics in disguise, too, like the Nigerian letter in your example).

Comment: @tripleee: Without getting into a semantic argument over the word "commercial," let me just say that many people have co-opted the word "spam" to mean "anything that's indiscriminately repeated," which is **not** what that word means, and why the definition we use here *must be specific.*

Comment: However, in the interest of détente, and since the word "commercial" does have the potential to confuse, I have modified my definition slightly.  Better?

Answer (score 21):

### What is spam in general?

#### Definitions

According to the [spam flag usage guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/163250):

> A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an [unsolicited advertisement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming).

and according to the flagging dialog itself:

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

I consider the 2<sup>nd</sup> definition above to be much more useful and accurate. **Spammers will often go to great lengths to make it non-obvious that what they're doing is advertising.** Only the most foolish of spammers will post something obvious along the lines of

> Go to my website www.example.com that is covered in ads that make me money! It has lots of awesome things that you will surely like!

#### Concealment

In order to succeed, spammers must ***trick users* into believing that spam content is not, in fact, just advertising.** Spammers will attempt to make their advertising appear contextual and relevant. Wordpress blogs get hosed with really subtle spam all the time. Spammers will post a comment that doesn't appear to contain any links, except that a commenter's username in Wordpress will often contain a link back to the spammer's blog:

[image: Spam screenshot]

That is an example Wordpress comment spam that someone left on a blog once (the date and profile image are not originals). The username "clash of clans gem hack" will often contain a link to a shady URL.

**Notice that there is no disclosure whatsoever that this is an advertisement.** However, it is ***effectively an advertisement***. The comment is just plain meaningless gibberish. The whole point of posting it was to get a link back to the poster's blog onto my site.

**Verdict: undisclosed, unsolicited advertisement.**

### This particular user's links back to AlgoQueue.com

Bluefeet gave [this reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260527/456814) for why she didn't consider this user's post to be spam:

> In my opinion, the user was attempting to answer the questions and instead of including the code they included a link to the code - which was wrong, but not spam.

I respect Bluefeet's opinion, and I greatly appreciate her efforts to moderate Stack Overflow fairly. However, I disagree with her assessment. Given the fact that this particular user posted [***22 low-quality answers***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350129/neel?tab=answers) in a period of 8 days, that all linked back to AlgoQueue.com, I would definitely consider this to be a slightly subtle mass spam campaign.

[I pointed out strong evidence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260524/how-should-i-have-handled-what-looked-like-spam-answers#comment42545_260527) that this was the case:

> I want to point out that this user has been posting links to [algoqueue.com](http://www.algoqueue.com/) since the start of June. According to [AlgoQueue's About page](http://www.algoqueue.com/algoqueue/default/about), they launched May of this year. It appears to be a Q&A site like Stack Overflow, but tailored to algorithms. They also run ads on the site. Most of the linked posts I've seen are by **REDACTED**, who according to LinkedIn, [is a technical writer there](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/AlgoQueue-8105248). She also may be based out of New York, where this "Neel" user says he's from in his profile.
>
> I could be wrong, but all of this strongly suggests undisclosed spam advertising to me.

Note that a day after I had pointed out that the linked posts were by **REDACTED**, someone who works at AlgoQueue, the linked posts suddenly had their author information removed. ***Someone*** at AlgoQueue is aware of [this comment on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260524/how-should-i-have-handled-what-looked-like-spam-answers#comment42545_260527), and has taken steps to remove some of the incriminating evidence.

I would be willing to let this particular user off the hook if this really was just a single uninformed incident...but this was definitely not a single, one-off incident. Again, this user posted ***22 low-quality answers with links to AlgoQueue*** in the span of a week. This is a pattern of behavior that strongly suggests that this was a mass-spam attempt.

Comment: For reference, the user in question was identified by moderators as an astroturfer, and was treated accordingly.  I concur with that assessment.  The user was answering questions; they were just putting the code of the answer on another site, presumably to get credit/mojo there, or whatever.  Almost certainly not a commercial advertisement.  You were right the first time; *A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an unsolicited commercial advertisement.*

Comment: Also, FWIW, we sometimes "remove the incriminating evidence" here, by deleting accounts (and thereby disassociating the author from their posts).