# Is this answer spam?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, spam

I encountered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24499982/507519) in my review queue. On one hand, it *seems* to be answering the question. On the other hand it is practically a link-only recommendation of a product, posted 4 years after the question. The same user has recommended the same product in at least [one more answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24499894/507519) of theirs within the last hour.

What should one do for such cases?

- Just vote for deletion as link-only answers?
- Flag as spam?
- Ask for moderator attention? (Or post in Meta...?)
- Ignore them, since they are sort-of related to the question, even if (n+1) years late?

I am leaning towards the first option, since spam flags have rather harsh penalties, but I'd like to hear the opinion of the community of the matter...

Comment: The question is closed, and will soon be deleted. The question of whether the answer was spam is somewhat irrelevant now.

Comment: @Cupcake: in any case someone *did* feel it deserved a spam flag...

Comment: This is one of the most clearest reasons why we don't allow tool recommendations, because they tend to attract spam or spam-like answers. Maybe flag the answer as being possibly overly self-promotional? There's not a log of clear evidence that the user is affiliated with the recommendation in this case though.

Comment: Hmm, both posts have been dealt with - deleted as spam. I guess I have my answer, so I'll be closing this question shortly...

Comment: That second answer was ***self-deleted***...oh wait, no, you're right, they were both deleted as spam from the review queue...it might not have been the right call in this case.

Comment: @Cupcake: they just seem to like that tool. That said, phrasing like "this *free* tool will make your life easier" is a little bit suspect...

Comment: I just realised that I cannot close my own question *just because*. I have to either self-answer it, delete it, or provide some bogus reason. Is there any reason to keep this question?

Comment: Related [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: Keep the question around for a bit.

Comment: I'd like to keep the question around -- it's relevant to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27726538/revisions) (which got deleted as spam before I could decide what I ought to do -- I guess someone else flagged it)

Comment: @Cupcake Still not deleted.