# In what situations are spam flags declined *by moderators*?

Tags: support, flags, spam, moderators

> **From the [Privileges - flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) article:**

> What happens when I flag something as spam or offensive?

> The spam and offensive flags are designed to automatically eliminate truly offensive posts through the collaboration of the community.

> - 3 flags -- post is banished from the front page.

- 6 flags -- post is locked, deleted, and the owner loses 100 reputation.

> Users with the [Moderator Tools privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can see how many offensive flags a post has accrued, and may opt to flag it themselves.

I'm confused as, per my reading of this paragraphs, it seems to denote that spam flags are managed by community effort, not moderators;

Here is my recent flag history flagged on [this event](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/potential-spam-2), which I believe should had been handled by community effort:

[image: x]

When do moderators review `spam` flags? (Is there a flag amount threshold before they should up in an exclusive moderator queue?)

Comment: PS I actually don't mind that it got declined, just curious.

Comment: Spam flags are visible to moderators; in many cases the spam post is deleted (by accumulating 6 flags) before one *looks* however.

Comment: In hindsight, I think I may have miscategorized [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21951845/1) as spam instead of "over self-promotion", according to Stack Exchanges definition.

Comment: @Cupcake: that user kept editing the post to draw attention, and posted *another* answer with the same link too. That user was spamming.

Comment: @Cupcake: It may have been a slightly grey area there as their link may have been mildly relevant to the (off-topic, request for external resources) question, but they weren't posting a proper answer either.

Comment: Related, but no longer a duplicate [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: Can 10K users even see spam flags anymore? If so, how?

Comment: Related: [stats on how many posts get deleted by the community via spam flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221337/around-how-many-questions-get-deleted-in-stack-exchange-and-by-who)

Comment: I had flagged a question as spam once because it was obviously not a real programming question but a political rant.  The flag was rejected by a moderator with a comment to next time down vote and/or vote to close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As soon as **single** spam or offensive flag is raised on a post we get to see it in the moderator dashboard. This means we can quickly look at the post and deal with it - often before other community members see it.

This is beneficial for a number of reasons:

1. We can go to the user's profile and check to see if they're a spammer or not. If they are a spammer then we can destroy the account. This removes any other posts they might have which haven't been seen/flagged yet and also feeds the automatic spam blocking system we have.
2. If the post isn't spam we can decline the flag and save the user from a potential 100 point rep penalty. This is important as people do flag stuff incorrectly.
3. It removes the spam from the system sooner than would be the case if we waited for the community to act.

Points 2 and 3 are important here as the consequences for leaving spam visible or incorrectly flagging something as spam are fairly serious.

If there aren't any moderators around (it does happen - especially on site with fewer than 17 moderators) then the community can act to by flagging to remove the spam.

Comment: "especially on site with fewer than 17 moderators" oh those poor sites, huh.

Answer (score 1):

Spam flags are *always* handled by moderators if there isn't a total of 6+ spam flags on the same post.
In the section you referred to:

- **3 flags -- post is banished from the front page** just means it will not show on the front page if it has acquired 3+ spam flags.
- **6 flags -- post is locked, deleted, and the owner loses 100 reputation**  means that a moderator does not need to review it because it is so obviously a spam post that 6 users have flagged it. The flags are automatically marked as helpful and the consequences of a spam flag take place.
- **Collaboration of the community** just means that if enough users flag the post, it is marked as spam.

Comment: So essentially, it isn't really "automatically eliminate"-d?

Comment: It is only automatically eliminated if the post received 6 or more spam flags.

Comment: @Unihedron it doesn't 100% qualify for "automatically eliminate" (which would be rather dangerous, if you think of it) - as [other answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268632/839601) explains, flag on the post is reviewed by moderator anyway. Spam deletion is designed to be as smooth as possible but not smoother :)