# Determining if this is spam/SEO-trick or just me being overly skeptic

Tags: discussion, questions, spam

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318676/i-am-trying-to-retrieve-the-index-of-a-value-in-array-1-and-use-that-index-to-fi). A seemingly decent question (meh), with way too much code that made little sense. It's in a format that's usually well received by many though as it's easy to answer and gets lots of attention.

But some of the variable names, and specifically one uninitialized variable, struck me as odd. So I googled, and it was the name of some Indian restaurant. To me the whole post and question feels a bit off, and I flagged it for *spam*. But I'm by no means sure! It might be perfectly legit naming for the purpose.

I'd love to hear if I'm in the right or wrong here, and also get some future guidance on cases like this. Am I being overly skeptic? Does it matter at all? Should I perhaps not have flagged this and just moved on?

Comment: They are Indian astrology terms, zodiac is the sun sign, rashi is the moon sign.

Comment: *"A seemingly decent question (meh), with way too much code that made little sense"* -> I believe this describes a significant percentage of all SO questions :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's certainly **not** spam.  There's a programming problem to be had here.

Since I work with so many languages nowadays, the symbols kind of blend together and form context, but I seldom stop to actually read what the variable name *is* unless it's critical to the program.  In that light, I didn't pick up on what your concern was for these variable names.  It may even be the case that the code is for an app for that restaurant.  (It really wouldn't surprise me.)

I don't see this as cause for alarm (as far as spam goes).  The question quality is questionable, but it's not spam.

Comment: What struck me as odd was that one variable, used several times, was never even initialized. Might of course just be a slip by the coder, but that was the reason I started to suspect it. I'll learn from my mistake and move on ;-)

Comment: I would attribute errors like that to genuine programming mistakes as opposed to something nefarious.  The former is *far* easier to prove out.

Comment: True, I'm overly suspicious. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It might very well be a project related to said restaurant. However, this post does not seem like spam to me. There is no indication of advertisement or anything else indicating spam.

Yes, the question has more code than necessary. But that doesn't make it spam either.

For what is and what is not spam, see [Robert Harvey's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/1014587) about it on MSO.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So _spam_ is for clear cut cases, and even if this turned out to be some SEO-thingie I shouldn't have used that flag. Got it! :)