# Why was a spam flag declined on a question that advertises to pay to solve a coding problem?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628717/coding-a-function) (10k+ only, it was deleted yesterday) as spam yesterday, because it's an unsolicited advertisement for someone willing to pay for solving a coding problem.  There is no presentation of a problem, only the solicitation of help by asking for contact information and the statement "I am willing to pay."

However, the flag was declined, with the reason "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Can someone please explain why this wasn't considered spam?  It certainly looks like spam to me, according to the guidelines laid out in [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow) and in [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work).

> A post should be marked as spam **ONLY** when it contains an unsolicited advertisement.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

While we obviously don't want this kind of content, it could simply be that this wasn't egregious enough. There were no links or advertisement.

While it *could* be seen as a job offer, its probably just a student who wants someone to do their work for them and doesn't understand how this site works. Considering the heavy penalties spam flags imply, it was simpler to just delete it (which the moderator did).

Comment: Where is the line between "don't want this kind of content" and "unsolicited advertisment"?

Comment: @rgettman Links/hidden links for starters. Intent (which of course is hard to judge) also comes into play

Comment: @rgettman: note that the term "spam" is generally reserved for _sales_. I.e. someone is _seeking_ payment for their services or goods, as opposed to in this case where someone was _offering_ payment. I realize it's a subtle difference, but IMHO the moderator made an excellent judgment call in spite of that subtlety. And Bradley's answer here does a very good job of concisely explaining that judgment call.

Comment: @rgettman This answer pretty much covers it. I processed the flag and didn't see it as spam, I saw it as a user who was desperate for help and went about it the wrong way.  I will apologize to you though, I should have disputed the flag instead of declining it. I can see why you thought it was spam.

Comment: @bluefeet: I thought [you couldn't dispute flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296218/my-declined-flag-was-eventually-implemented#comment203506_296218)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Moderator flags, NAA, VLQ cannot be disputed. Spam/Offensive can.

Comment: @bluefeet: Ah ok ;P