# My declined flag was eventually implemented

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, answer-quality, popularity, protected-questions

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python) as potentially needing to be protected. It was declined. Three weeks later, the question was protected.

It's clear that the question was protected due to a surge in popularity rather as a response to my flag, so it's not like someone went "denied! now let me go protect that" or anything. But still, prophesy.

Does the system have any way to acknowledge this sort of thing, like a flag-review-review (e.g. "this flag declination has been declined"), or an Internet cookie (badge), or something? As it is, it feels like telling the boss about an idea for a cool new widget, getting rejected, and then seeing the widget a few weeks later on a shopping trip.

Comment: What was the reason given when it was declined?

Comment: My flag pointed out the appearance of several derivative answers, and the declination reason was "Protect only works on low-rep users."

Comment: Well, whoever declined was right in pointing out it would be useless there...

Comment: Yes, but perhaps those answers were the drop in pressure before the storm and my barometer is good.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Can I see the flag's message verbatim?

Comment: "Might need to be protected - nearly half of the answers are copycats of previous answers."

Comment: Were I a diamond, perhaps I would have marked that disputed instead (which I believe is an option for them), but otherwise, yeah, this is just one of those unfortunate rough edges. It *would* be nice to have a way of re-validating flags that turn out correct, but so far it hasn't been worth the trouble of building the system.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Moderators can't dispute flags, we can mark them helpful or declined.

Comment: @bluefeet: I guess I was mistaken. Good to know.

Comment: @bluefeet Do you think that would be a useful middle ground, if they *could* mark a flag as disputed? As if to say, "The flag is not completely invalid, I just don't agree."

Comment: @Chris Baker: I'd just mark it as helpful in that case. A helpful flag has merit but may not necessarily result in action taken.

Answer (score 36):

An arbitrary SO user passed by, not a moderator, he had enough rep to protect the question without requiring assistance from a moderator or have his action subjected to review.  Something anybody can do once they have 15,000 points.

His action has no connection whatsoever with your flag, or the reason a moderator declined it, he was completely unaware of it.  Whether it was correct for him to protect the question is not at issue, any other user with enough rep can simply unprotect it again.  I doubt anybody will.

Answer (score 11):

You requested that the question be protected due to copycat answers. I'm not the moderator who declined your flag, but the copycat answers you refer to were all posted by users with hundreds to even *thousands* of reputation points (and I did check the rep history of all the recent posters to see if they had that much at the time of posting). There were no answers posted by drive-by users, and so there was no point protecting the question as it would simply not stop established users from posting more answers. For this reason, I would have declined your flag as well.

If the user who protected the question later did do so on the basis of popularity as you surmise, then that is somewhat different. A surge in popularity would imply a possibility of more drive-by or low-rep users posting copycat answers, so protecting a question would certainly have been effective. But the mere presence of copycat answers alone does not warrant protection *unless* the vast majority of such answers were posted by users who would be blocked by protection.