# Why does Stack Overflow redirects from incomplete question URLs to complete?

Tags: support

For example `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296102/why-was-a-spam-flag-declined-on-a-question-that-advertises-to-pay-to-solve-a-cod` can't be viewed as `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296102/`, the server redirects back to the first URL.

It causes our network firewall to block certain URL because it detects some banned keywords, I suppose it's due to the "advertise" in it.

On other sites where this filter has blocked some pages I would simply omit the human readable part of the URL so no offending keywords would block its load, currently Stack Overflow is the only that performs a redirect to the full form in such a case, thus permanently blocking loading of some pages.

Comment: They are both the same question...

Comment: Eh, right? But the URLs are not. Why did you NOT read the whole question? What on Earth makes people rush to post w/o thinking?

Comment: Have you seen what your post looks like? Anyways, it's a problem with your local firewall and quite naive blocks. Talk with your sysadmin to fix it. The reason why is already asked elsewhere.

Comment: Did you try to visit those pages over https:// instead of http://?

Comment: Serving a full page under both URLs would mean there's two pages for each question; while duplicate content problems could be solved using a "canonical" Meta tag, it would still be kind of silly from an engineering perspective. Having the version with the title as the canonical version, and having everything else redirect there is just nice, and 100% safe from a search engine perspective

Answer (score 7):

The important part of the URL is the part up to the question id:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296102/
```

This will never change so this will always return the same question.

The rest of the url is the title of the question when the url was generated. So if I have:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296102/a-really-bad-question-title
```

that's not very helpful, but will still return the same question were I to change it to:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296102/a-much-better-descriptive-title
```

Doing it this way normally gives a much better user experience.

I'm not sure why your company firewall would block the url, but if you simply remove the part after the id there are no keywords for it to trigger on.

Comment: *Better user experience* - Yes! It's easier to find out dupe targets by typing a few keywords in the browser search bar than by typing out the question ID.

Comment: @BhargavRao One could argue you are supposed to use Stack Overflow's dupe searcher instead of your browser history. The problem is that the dupe searcher sucks.

Comment: @Oriol Funny that you mentioned the dupe searcher. It reminds me of this https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv3ta.jpg. Hopefully things will improve when those bunch of Aussie researchers help SE fix it.

Comment: Another reason to do these sort of redirects is to prevent abuse. For example consider URLs such as `http://example.com/153645-trump-sexist-pig` or `http://example.com/153645-clinton-commits-voter-fraud`. The content of the articles doesn't really have to match up, "reading a book only by the it's title" is hardly a new concept, and in the age of "social media" and rampant conspiracy mongering it's only gotten worse. You want to protect your platform from this sort of abuse.