# How to reply to a "I'm willing to pay" comment?

Tags: support, etiquette, rules

I recently had a reply from the OP to a comment including "Also I am happy to pay you something if you can make it work."

To be honest, I replied suggesting to contact me through LinkedId but then I realized that this could be against the site rules so I deleted  this comment.

Are these interactions, offering to pay point the "client" to another place / contact information allowed or should I point the OP to my profile? Could I add a donate / pay me instructions on my Profile Bio?

---

NOTES:

I'm not requiring the OP for a payment to answer their question, I'm giving suggestions of help articles / references to read that could help them to write a good question.

Related

- [Why was a spam flag declined on a question that advertises to pay to solve a coding problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296102/1595451)

Comment: Relevant [MSE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190877/is-it-acceptable-to-solicit-money-on-a-user-profile).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276249/6296561

Comment: @gnat "Are job offers spam" is about posting job offers as question, not about doing that on comments.

Comment: Say "No thank you, but I will help anyway".

Comment: I don't think it is terrible if you have a short conversation about paid services, if that what someone has asked for (though it is true that they should not be adding such requests to their questions). Comments don't exactly get filed as "off topic" in the way that a question can, but you can certainly expect a conversation about paid support to be deleted if it is flagged.

Answer (score 3):

My conclusions:

- Flag comments offering a payment / hiring as "noise"
- Suggest the OP to look at their favorite community members profiles to see if they included some way to contact / hire them
- Update my Bio

References

- [What to do when OP offers payment for solution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316137/1595451)
- [Is it acceptable to solicit money on a user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190877/289691)