# Failed audit on a (not really) link-only answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9283878) LQ review audit, and now I'm blocked for a week.

The answer can't be seen anymore (it's since been deleted, I assume), but it was an answer with a link to a library. I did not flag as link-only, however, because it included a significant amount of explanation as to why this particular library solved this user's problem, which is my own heuristic for whether a link answer is acceptable or not.

I wasn't familiar with the library in question, so maybe the answer was inappropriate for technical reasons I didn't notice.

I'm still getting the hang of some of the new review queues I got access to at >2000 rep. I need to learn how to do this properly. Should I:

- Modify my heuristic and fail all answers that boil down to links to resources, even if it includes a good explanation or examples as to why that resource or library answers the question
- Pay attention to whether the answer has downvotes, as a measure of whether the community feels the answer is good or not
- Skip reviews that aren't in my own area of technical expertise (PHP in this case)
- Be Jon Skeet at all times (...simple!)

Comment: Deleted by owner.  Maybe due to cautions about spam (no disclosure)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Spam because it's advertising a particular library? I'm not familiar with "Vagrant/Homestead" and I can't click on the link, is that a commercial service or something?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Whether its free or not is irrelevant as to whether it's spam or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is a bit let's say interesting. The content of the answer is:

> [image]

I agree that it's not link-only.

The problem is that it was flagged as spam, the user who posted the answer self-deleted it with the active spam flag, which, in turn, marked the flag as helpful. As a result, this became an audit.

That question has gathered several other (now deleted) answers which seem to be pushing libraries, but I wouldn't say that particular answer is spam, so to me it's a bad audit.  I've cleared the spam flags but kept the answer deleted which should help with this weird audit.

Comment: sure looks like spam to me; I don't see a reason to clear the spam flag.

Comment: Sorry if this has been answered definitively before: are **all** recommendations for a library (even open-source/non-commercial stuff) considered spam? Is there a way to recommend a resource like the above without being spammy? [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/3191599) definition of spam is talking about *advertisement*, which seems distinct from "here is an open source library to solve your problem", to me. What's the rule?

Comment: @Servy I'm giving the user the benefit of the doubt on this. It's a detailed answer, they have no other posts similar to this (i.e. pushing this library).

Comment: @NateBarbettini Well, first, recommendation questions are off-topic and they should be closed not answered. Things can be spammed in a variety of ways - "hey buy this" links, "hey use this library" links, "hey go to this website" links - you need to use your own judgment on whether or not you think something is spam. My interpretation of this answer is - it's not spam.

Comment: @bluefeet Got it, thanks. I also interpreted the answer as not-spam because the author was not (as far as I could tell) related to or profiting from the development of the library he linked to, so it wasn't "advertisement" in my mind.

Comment: @bluefeet But it's completely unrelated to the question.  The OP stated that he was having a specific problem with a specific tool and this guy posts an answer just to say, "you should just drop that and use my tool instead" follow by what looks like the about page of that product (rather than anything even remotely related to the OP's issue).

Comment: @Servy As I said, I'm giving them the benefit of the doubt on it. It's deleted but they don't get the penalty of a spam answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would still be a loss to ignore the point list, regardless of the fact that the offending answer has been dealt with. The following are my experiences being in the same boat as you (recent 2k passing, hello big brave world of stackoverflow). I hope other people share ideas about what to do and wat not to do too.

> Modify my heuristic and fail all answers that boil down to links to
>   resources, even if it includes a good explanation or examples as to
>   why that resource or library answers the question

No, that's too black & white and an aspect of robo-reviewing. Sometimes a library or framework IS the answer to a valid question, if you can explain it. I would rather park such an answer for a moment and look at the question being asked; answers providing a recommendation for a library often are paired with off-topic questions asking for them. If you'd only address the answer, you'd only be addressing the symptom and not the cause.

> Pay attention to whether the answer has downvotes, as a measure of
>   whether the community feels the answer is good or not

Meh. You can't see **who** downvoted and for what reason, and as such I myself don't take too much stock of downvotes, unless there are a lot of course.  Besides reviewing is about what you know and think, not about what the community thinks it knows. The community can be completely wrong too.

> Skip reviews that aren't in my own area of technical expertise (PHP in
>   this case)

This depends on how strong your reasoning skills are; me personally I tend to skip them if there isn't anything particularly wrong outside of corrections to code that do not represent a complete overhaul. It isn't fair to review something based on partial guesswork, be it either to approve or to reject; it needs a certain level of confidence behind it.

And there is absolutely no shame in hitting "skip".

> Be Jon Skeet at all times

Jon Skeet is only Jon Skeet because he chooses to be himself even in an online environment. If you want to be Jon Skeet, you have to stay Nate Barbettini.