# Review audit and guidelines

Tags: discussion, feature-request, disputed-review-audits

Yesterday I was feeling for trying to go through the Low Quality post queue. After recommending deletion for quite a few posts I stumbled upon this https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16468204 which I felt was at least border line ok after viewing the question with comments.

I understand that the audits are automatic and there could be ambiguous posts. However, it would be great with some guidelines on what should be ok, and if you fail an audit, it would be great with a reason why the audit fails.

As it stands now I cannot find any guidance on how to review LQ posts.

My suggestion would be that all questions that are selected for an audit has a clear reason why the question should have been deleted so we understand the error we made in selecting `Looks ok`.

This might mean the moderator closing the question should write a reason why for it to be selected in an audit.

This put me off reviewing LQ posts; randomly failing audits is not a good feeling. I've been doing a lot of reviewing in suggested edits and have not had much problems with that queue so I would say it's queue dependent.

[image: Screenshot of question]

Comment: *This put me off reviewing LQ posts* ... I think that may be the point. It's definitely put more than a few of us off reviewing...

Comment: Links to third-party sites should be a trigger for: you should pay a bit more attention. Is it a link to a private blog or app from the poster (i.e. advertisement)? Is it a common site (i.e. fine to link to)? Or is that link otherwise suspicious (i.e. ref-link or points to a different site than expected (like "[answer] ... further reading: good-site.com" but then links to bad-site.com)? If that link isn't that easy to decide and you don't want to dig a bit deeper, then prefer to skip the review. This case here might be from a user who linked to his Github to advertise his project(s) there.

Comment: And you also need to check such posts for being "link-only", but this isn't the case here.

Comment: @Tom my feature request is to be given the clear reason why this triggered a failed audit. As it stands now I was given no reason.

Comment: @tom also it looks like it was migrated to a comment by the moderator. Look at the original question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132924/matlab-imwrite-error-in-certain-folders

Comment: Or that comment was there already and the poster also used its content as an answer. We'll know when that mod writes a comment about this here.

Comment: @Tom & jontro It was definitely converted to a comment. When I look at the review task (and the deleted answer), it explicitly states that the answer was converted to a comment by deceze♦. In other words, where the screenshot in the question shows "deleted by [deceze♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) May 24 at 23:51", I see "converted to a comment by [deceze♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) May 24 at 23:51". I assume this difference is a >=10k rep feature.

Comment: @Makyen I can't even see the answer and need the provided screenshot for that, so I would also assume that this is a >10k feature. Thanks for letting us know that there is such a comment, but I wonder if not everybody should be able to it. At least in a review.

Comment: **[There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)** <--- that's the main guidance

Comment: @gnat I would say that's not the case here. I skip when I am unsure

Comment: if you are sure that this "Looks OK" then, well, audit did the right thing teaching you that it really doesn't

Comment: @gnat The answer isn't great, and saying that there's no action needed in something like First Posts would be wrong, but the post doesn't merit deletion from LQP, so yes, the user *did* do the right thing.  The moderator that acted on that post incorrectly marked an answer as spam, despite it not actually being spam, and actually being an answer to the question (albeit not a good one).

Comment: no @Servy the user did the wrong thing. I agree with both points in your assessment that the answer isn't great and that it doesn't merit deletion (or more precisely the latter should be stated like "it would take me too much effort to find whether it merits deletion or not"). But conclusion you make from this is entirely wrong: reviewer shouldn't press "Looks OK" - and [the main review guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) referred in my prior comment explains clearly what is the right course of action here

Comment: @gnat When a post looks okay and doesn't merit any action from the review the correct course of action *is* to say that it looks okay.  Skipping is something that you do when you don't know what the correct action is.  Here the user *did* know what the correct course of action was, and they took it.  Skipping posts that you *know* don't merit any action from the queue is *incorrect*.  Your assertion that it would take you more time than you want to spend figuring out the correct course of action doesn't make it wrong for someone else to actually take the time and choose the correct action.

Comment: @Servy again, I agree that when a post looks okay the correct course of action is to say that it looks okay. But the [post discussed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZEbQ.png) doesn't

Comment: ...and please stop pretending that you do diamond's mod job in LQ queue. You're not deciding on flags, you're deciding on posts. To decide that post _Looks OK_ make sure that 1) it is clearly written and well formatted (edit if necessary). 2) Check the question and make sure that post looks like a relevant answer to it. 3) Check other answers to make sure that it doesn't repeat / plagiarises prior ones. 4) If points #1-3 look like too much work to you, well, act per [main guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip). Simple as that

Comment: @gnat The post *does* look okay. There are no actions that are appropriate to take from that queue *other* than to say that it looks okay. The post has problems, but it doesn't have problems *that the queue is there to solve*.  If you want to go to the post directly and take some additional actions, outside of the queue, you certainly *can*, but you're not *obligated* to.  The OP *did* their due diligence to ensure that the post didn't merit any moderation action from the queue, and it didn't, so they *correctly* indicated as much by marking the post as no action needed.

Comment: @Servy you are not only wrong, you are misleading the reviewer. At the very least post is in the need for edit (including but not limited to properly presenting bare URL in there). This option is very prominently present in LQ queue UI. And it is in the need of comment suggesting author to better explain how their suggestion addresses the question asked

Comment: @gnat You are not only wrong, you are misleading the reviewer.  The LPQ queue doesn't exist to fix minor formatting problems with posts.  It's there to delete posts that are complete garbage.  If you want to spend time fixing formatting problems with posts then you should be in first/last post, HI, or possibly suggested edits.  There is an edit option, yes, and it's for posts that *seem* extremely low quality, of such low quality that they may end up getting deleted, but that you can salvage, such as by taking a link only answer and incorporating the relevant section into a quote.

Comment: @gnat But just because there is a way to edit posts in that queue doesn't mean it's wrong to mark a post as looking okay when it is very clearly an answer, doesn't merit deletion for any reason, but has some minor formatting problems.  That would be true in any of the other queues I listed, because fixing such formatting problems *is the goal of those queues*, but not in LQP.  The same is true of comments explaining problems with a post not significant enough to merit deletion; that's not what this queue is for.

Comment: @Servy you are again wrong, and queue UI proves just that. Edit option is there for a reason, its very presence demonstrates that it is not about only choosing whether to delete or keep. Editing importance is further stressed by the fact that these unilaterally drop the posts off the queue - it is expected of editor to bring podst in such a state that it won't mislead readers into thinking that it's of low quality again

Comment: @gnat You are again wrong, and the queue's guidelines prove that.  The edit option *is* there for a reason, and that reason is not because you're obligated to fix every tiny problem that you see in a post; that's the job of other queues.  There's also the fact that for quite a while the option didn't even exist, just as there was no edit option when reviewing suggested edits, in both cases an edit option was provided for those that want to go *beyond the expectations of the queue* and fix other problems.

Comment: @Servy I agree that edits in LQ queue are not for fixing tiny issues. You are wrong in that you consider problems in the [post discussed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZEbQ.png) tiny

Comment: @gnat The formatting of the link *is* tiny.  The real problem with the post is its lack of explanation, which you can't really fix with editing.

Comment: @Servy if you would think of (possibly hundreds or even thousands) future readers bare URL formatting wouldn't look so tiny. As for lack of explanation, no it is in the options, just not immediately. To address this issue reviewer is expected to click the link to post and comment from there. Again, if that looks like too much work, refer [main review guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) on what is expected of reviewer in that case

Comment: @gnat Again, that's a good thing to do, in general, but *it's not what that queue is there for*.  It's something that would be expected of a first post or a last post review, but the LQP queue isn't there to find and fix every problem with a post, it's there to determine if a post *needs to be deleted or not*.  This post does not.  Doing any more than that is certainly welcome, but not required.  Note that if you *did* go above expectations and comment, then the correct course of action after doing so *would still be to mark the post as okay*.

Comment: @Servy we seem to have different expectations and I fail to find what your are based on besides your personal beliefs. Mine expectations are based on a meta post that gained wide consensus and was additionally [supported by community manager in another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153279/165773) and on what everyone can observe in LQ queue UI and workflow. If you presented similarly or more compelling evidence in favor of your expectations I would consider changing mine. But as far as I can tell you didn't

Comment: @gnat So your justification for why the LQP queue exists to do more than determine if a post should be deleted is to link to a post claiming that a substantial edit to a post should be approved in the situation described?  That post has no relevance on the discussion at hand.  It says *nothing* about users being obligated to find and fix every problem in a post in the LQP queue.  Additionally linking a meta post saying that if you don't know what you should do then you should skip *also* doesn't say that LQP is there to edit and comment on moderate quality posts.

Comment: @gnat [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/186381) you can see the guidelines for using the queue in the FAQ.  Note that it *specifically* says that the edit option *isn't* for minor edits; it's only for editing a post that's currently below the level of "acceptability" if you can edit to to be *above* that level.  Making a link look a bit prettier doesn't fall into that category.  Note it also specifically says that "looks okay" *is* the correct course of action for a post that's just wrong, or otherwise acceptable (i.e. not delete worthy) but still not a *good* answer.

Comment: @gnat the edit button exists in the LQPRQ for the same reason it exists in the CVRQ. It exists so that if you are served a review of a post that is unacceptable in its current state, but can be made acceptable through edits without changing the meaning of the post, you can edit it to _prevent_ it from being deleted (or closed in the CVRQ). If the post is already acceptable, it is not _required_ that anyone edit it in the LQPRQ. It is a good idea, but it isn't required.

Comment: @Servy FAQ you referred doesn't seem to match the approach you propose for reviewing the post we discuss. You mentioned that post lacks explanation - per my reading of your FAQ in cases like that reviewer is expected to comment / vote down but you seem to suggest that it's enough to just click Looks OK, how's that? Also I found nothing there to support your idea that bare URLs like in discussed post are a tiny matter - is this merely your personal belief or you can back it up somehow?

Comment: @gnat Per the instructions there they can comment if they feel it's appropriate, they're welcome to leave the queue and downvote if they want (they of course *can't* do so from the queue even if they wanted to ) and then to mark the post as "looks okay".  Your assertion that the post shouldn't be marked as okay then is simply false.  If you want to assert that having a link in a post, as opposed to linked text, is something so severe that a post needs to be delete, then you're going to need to support that assertion.

Comment: @Servy why do you put words in my mouth when you absolutely clearly know that this is not what I mean. I never meant to say that post needs to be delete, this is even explicitly stated in my very first comment to you here: "I agree with both points in your assessment that the answer isn't great and that it doesn't merit deletion..."

Comment: @gnat Then you understand that the review action of "looks okay" is correct.  If the post doesn't merit deletion, then *that is not an incorrect course of action*.  The only time that clicking that button *isn't* acceptable is if the post merits deletion.

Comment: @Servy as I already explained I fail to see how this matches the FAQ you referred

Comment: @gnat By all means, quote the section where it says that it's inappropriate to mark a post as looks okay when it doesn't merit deletion.

Comment: @Servy there you go: "Bad formatting, spelling, structure and language: Improve it or leave a comment to the author. If there is no other problem and the post is understandable, choose Looks OK." (per my reading this means one is expected to click looks OK only after commenting / editing)

Comment: @gnat So you've just quoted a section saying that the correct action is to choose "looks okay".  I asked you to provide a quote of where it described how choosing "looks okay" is the *inappropriate* action to choose here, you've provided a quote saying specifically the opposite.

Comment: @Servy my understanding is for the review we discuss you suggest that it would be correct to only click Looks OK without commenting / editing / voting, do I got it right? I ask because that's where I see mismatch, my reading of FAQ suggests these actions are necessary prior to clicking Looks OK

Comment: @gnat No.  All of those actions are helpful (when warranted), and more than welcome, but not *mandatory*.  There's a big difference.  What's mandatory is that you delete things that merit deletion, and keep things that merit keeping.  The rest is gravy.

Comment: oh then we read the same FAQ differently @Servy

Comment: @gnat Then please, by all means, point out where it says what you claim.  The post even goes out of it's way to *specifically* point out that minor edits shouldn't be made from the queue, as that is a unilateral decision, and that it should only be done when you're sure you're fixing the root cause that causes the post to not be acceptable, and have made it acceptable.  The rest of the actions aren't even actions in the queue, they're actions *outside of the queue*.

Comment: I already quted that part @Servy: "Bad formatting, spelling, structure and language: Improve it or leave a comment to the author. If there is no other problem and the post is understandable, choose Looks OK." And please note that I found nothing in there suggesting that edit we discuss here is minor, I already mentioned that

Comment: @gnat Those are all things that you're welcome to do.  As I said, quote where it says that those things are mandatory, and that it's wrong to not do them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow)

> ## What is Spam?
>
> Spam is an **unsolicited commercial advertisement**. We've all seen it, and we all know what it looks like. It looks like the same stuff you see in your spam folder when you look at your email.

Spam exists **solely** to promote a product or service. For a post to be spam, it must not be an attempt to answer the question, and it must be **unsolicited**. If someone asks a question asking how to accomplish a task, and someone answers with a link to a product or service that accomplishes that task, **that answer is not spam**.

As for why this answer is technically an attempt to answer and should not have been converted to a comment by a moderator, I will direct you to: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Now the reason that this is a problem is that it has been deleted by a moderator so it can only be undeleted by someone with moderator powers. This is why moderators are usually reluctant to act in cases such as this, so I'm unsure as to why this moderator chose to take action in this case.

As for guidance reviewing in the LQPRQ (Low Quality Posts Review Queue), the best guidance I can give you is to read the answer/castle post I linked above, then read: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).

Rest assured, you chose the correct action in this case.

Comment: I've cleared the spam flag, and reversed the conversion to a comment, so this shouldn't present a problem going forward. If only [there was a way to dispute individual audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790) like this...