# Review rejected spam flag

Tags: support, declined-flags, spam

I flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597851/python-programming-language/44597898#44597898) as spam a few days ago which was declined. Where might I have gone wrong?

Screenshot of the (now deleted) answer:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Spam", as SE defines it, is *unsolicited* advertisements (or advertisements that are otherwise inappropriate, such as astroturfing, or not disclosing affiliation when required, see the help center for details).

Here the suggestion to use the product is on topic for the question (although the question itself is off topic, precisely because questions like this attract answers like these) which means that a spam flag isn't appropriate.

What *is* appropriate for the mod is to just delete the whole question, which they did.

For a post like this to be spam you'd probably need to have the question author being "in on it" and knowingly posting the question specifically so that they (possibly using another account) could post an answer like the one you flagged.

Comment: That's not true. This is an unsolicited ad, for these learning apps, so it is spam broadly speaking. Martijn even said the rejection was probably a misclick. Tbh, any undisclosed advertising is spam really.

Comment: And Spam on SE is **undisclosed** and/or unsolicited ads

Comment: I always thought solicited ads were considered spam too, but I know the bar is set quite high for spam here.

Comment: @cpburnz if solicited ads with full disclosure form a small part of a users posts, then it is tolerated. Otherwise, **no**. See [Promotion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for more info.

Comment: @Magisch But it's not.  Did you read the question?  The question is *asking* for answers like these.  The answer *actually answers the question*.  It's not even clear to me that the answerer is affiliated with the product; they just look like someone that's used it and like it.  Considering the other posts from that user, this in fact seems more likely than it being an account created just to advertise a product.

Comment: @Magisch: I must say I didn't look at the question though; the question does make it semi-solicited. It's a rather spammy answer still, but the question did *solicit* the answer.

Comment: The flag was also possibly declined because there doesn't seem to be any connection between the user and the product. They have a number of other answers and questions, none of which were related to this, and I don't see anything obvious about their profile that would connect them to this company. Typically, spammers start posting promotional answers immediately or do so in large groups of posts. They typically don't post a bunch of technical answers and then post a single piece of spam. Personally, I probably would have cleared (disputed) the flag, but I can see why it was declined.

Comment: The question has been deleted now, could any 10k user please show it?

Comment: And now we need a connection between the user doing promotion and the thing being promoted to be spam... do anyone knows the frigging definition of spam? Unsolicited message: we want answers that explain how to solve the question, not simply products but *solutions*.

Comment: @Braiam The question is *asking for products*, so the answer *is doing exactly that*.  Recommendation a product in a product recommendation question isn't spam.

Comment: @Servy then this discussion is sillier: **delete the question**.

Comment: @Braiam The moderator *did* delete the question.  They choose to delete the question *instead* of the answer.  Did you not read my post, where I specifically say that the proper course of action here is to delete the question, which is exactly what the moderator did?  (Nor did you actually look at the post itself, which would have also told you as much.)

Comment: @BradLarson is exactly right - when I looked into this I see a constructive user trying to answer a bad question. Are they misguided? Sure. Are they a spammer who should rot in the fires of hell? No. I probably should have disputed instead of decline though, because it could have gone either way.

Comment: @Braiam [Spam is an **unsolicited commercial advertisement**.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/4639281). If the question asks how to solve a problem and the answer recommends a product or service that solves that problem, or the question is specifically asking for references to products or services (such a question would be off-topic) and someone posts and answer referencing a product or service, that answer is not spam.

Comment: @TinyGiant MSE > MSO; Jeff > everyone else: spam is ["the strict traditional internet definition"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56224/213575), which "is the use of electronic messaging systems to send an unsolicited message (spam)", according to wikipedia. Don't try to argue this with me, try to argue it with Jeff. I'm not going to respond to any message twisting a very clear cut definition, which comes from the horse mouth in plain simple english. Don't agree? I don't care.

Comment: @Braiam A wrong answer is spam by your definition (I solicited a correct answer, not a wrong answer). You're basically saying that any NAA, VLQ, or post that is otherwise not what was asked for is spam. Don't agree? I don't care.

Comment: The amount of time we spend discussing and refining the taxonomy of garbage on this site boggles the mind.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you sure, some think it isn't enough, and it's normally the ones that seems to have their own interpretation of the english.

Comment: @Braiam If you want to be upset at SE for using a non-standard definition for "spam", then by all means.  If you want to write up a proposal to rename the "spam" flag to something that better indicates that it's not exactly the same as the standard English definition, you go right ahead.  But the fact remains that SE has a well defined set of criteria for when the "spam" *flag* is appropriate, and it's not the definition you provided, and the post in question here doesn't merit the flag.

Comment: @Braiam It's of course worth pointing out that even though your definition isn't SE's definition, and isn't describing exactly when you should or shouldn't use a spam flag, the post in question **doesn't even meet your definition of spam**.  It's providing a *solicited* answer *that actually answers the question*.  Nothing about the post meets either your *or* SE's definition of spam.

Comment: Don't joke around, SE **is using a very standard definition of spam**. Heck, Jeff even linked to wikipedia instead. I'm actually quite frustrated that you all keep redefining spam instead of using SE's which is Wikipedia's

Comment: @Braiam Just because Jeff wrote one thing in one meta post 7 years ago doesn't necessarily mean that's official policy (today).  Feel free to read through the description of the flag, and the help center section on "spam" if you want to see SE's criteria for what merits the "spam" flag.  It's not *radically* different, but it's not exactly the same either.  Going around telling people to flag things that a mod is just going to decline, possibly even resulting in further action taken against them, isn't going to be helpful to anyone.

Comment: You didn't find anyone contradicting Jeff, right? So, until then what Jeff wrote back then is still the same. Like the 6 characters edit limit and whatever else was done in Jeff time.

Comment: @Braiam I sure did.  I even pointed it out to you in my previous comment.  Read the flag description.  Read the help center.  *That* is the canonical source on how to use the flag, not some random meta post from Jeff from 7 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

> I flagged an answer as spam a few days ago which was declined. Where might I have gone wrong?

There was a bigger issue in this context: the question itself was asking for products, which is kinda what the answer gave. So, repeat the mantra:

## Problem questions, generate problem answers

If you find a problematic answer, it's very likely that the question is asking for those kind of answers.