# How to distinguish between spam and non-spam answer, and how to bring it into moderator's attention

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, disputed-flags, moderators

**Overview Of the Problem**

I recently noticed a user who was promoting his website in all the answers related to a specific topic. In fact, he has given 13 of the answers with the exactly same content pointing to his website out of around 15-16 answers he has contributed in total.

**Why am I asking this?**

I marked all the 13 answers as spam because the user was doing promotion of the website which belongs to him and he didn't undisclosed his association with the site. And he was doing it repeatedly. But 11 of my flags were marked as disputed, and only 2 of them were marked as helpful. (Though all the answers I marked as spam are showing up as deleted by moderator.)

**Why I chose the spam flag?**

Spam flag says:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the
>   author's affiliation.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

And in the embed link, it is mentioned:

> **The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam**. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen
>   to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must
>   disclose your affiliation in your answers.

**Details related to problem**

Screenshot of the one such answer (all the other answers were exactly or almost same)

[image: Disputed Answer Screenshot]

Here's the question for which this answer was provided:

[image: Related Question]

Even though it is related in *some way*, but it is not the answer to the Question. I can share the link to all the answers, but it will reveal the identity of the user and I don't think it'll be a good idea. If that is required, I can share that too.

**Why I am so bothered?**

- I want to know the protocol so that my future flags do not go into the disputed flag category.
- 11 of my flags are marked as disputed in a single night which impacts my profile. Earlier I use to have a decent flag history, but not any longer. :|
- It will also help other SO folks who are sailing in the same boat. Because if I am wrong here to flag the answer as spam, others must have faced it too; because the documentation in that case tells a different story.

**My Questions**

1. Does it falls under the category of *spam* answer or not?
2. If yes, is there any specific reason why my flags were marked as disputed? *(11 out of 13)*
3. If it is not a spam, what should I have done in this case?

Comment: Sometimes moderators will go to great lengths to avoid imposing the -100 rep spam penalty if the person has made other valuable contributions. Doesn't make much sense considering these are the only people who can be impacted by that penalty in the first place, but that's how it's been explained to me in the past.

Comment: If that's the case, it is not applicable here. Because rest of the 2-3 answers by him (i.e. all the answers apart from the answer I flagged) didn't made much sense to me. But since those were not spam, I skipped them. Though I wanted to flag/down-vote them too, but I didn't have enough knowledge of the topic on which they were posted, which stopped me to take any action.

Comment: The phrase "let us know if you have questions or need help with anything" surely indicates the author is affiliated. I'm not sure an explicit "Disclaimer: I work for the company" or whatever adds anything additional.

Comment: @MartinSmith You may consider it, but the first line contradicts that statement *"There's an API ..."* . Also, *"let us know if you .."* can be used by anyone having expertise in that field. BTW added snippet of the Question as well for which this was answered, which will make my point more clear

Comment: Yes definitely on the spectrum of spam but looks like there was some element of disclosure and some attempt to post on relevant questions so maybe that was sufficient to avoid the spam penalty. I have no idea what that actual product is they are promoting though. Why would you need a company logo API?

Comment: "Disputed" is not the same as "Declined". Spam and rude/abusive flags are the only ones moderators can "dispute". It means that the flag has merit, but we don't feel that it's 100% warranted. Don't forget these flags come with a serious -100 point reputation penalty and if we're not sure we don't want to get it wrong. Clearly as Alex points out in their [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354548/59303) whoever handled the flags thought the answers weren't spam to start off with but then realised they were and validated the rest.

Comment: I normally flag these sorts of things for moderator attention and note in the message that this user is excessively promoting their own product. That way it's up to the moderator to decide if it's really spam or not, and either way the flag will probably be marked helpful because the user is not using the site the way it's meant to be used and the mods will at least need to communicate with that user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a difference between excessive self-promotion and spam.

- Excessive self-promotion occurs when a user answers a question (or at least tries to), but unnecessarily promotes the user's own site or products, especially without disclosure.
- By contrast, on these sites, "spam" has a very specific meaning:

  > Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

  It also carries with it some hefty penalties, such as a reputation penalty and IP-blocking.

You should read [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/2057919), which offers some good insight into the distinction.

The posts you flagged were, in "normal" terms, kinda spammy. But they didn't fit the "spam" definition above because they didn't exist *only* to promote a product or service, and they *kind of* had disclosures, such as, "Let us know if you have problems."

The appropriate action here would have been to raise an "other" flag and explain the problem, rather than spam flags. From the link above:

> ## How do I report excessive or improper promotion?
>
> To have a user reviewed for excessive promotion, flag one of their answers using a custom moderator flag, and explain the problem.

Comment: Exactly. I'm the one who processed these flags, and while I agreed that the posts were inappropriate, I did not think that they deserved the -100 point penalty because I felt the user had good intentions and just needed some clarification about our rules. Therefore, I deleted the posts, but cleared the spam flags, which marked them as "disputed". I also addressed this with the user, so hopefully there will not be any more problems in the future. If there are, it will become straight-up spam. FWIW, I think the spam flags were okay here. Just don't worry about "disputed".

Answer (score 1):

If answer looks like answer but you believe it is actually spam for some reason it would be better to mark as it as other (maybe in addition to spam) as to my understanding there is not much context shown when handling each particular flag.

So my guess what happened is one or even several moderators declined spam flags first, but after seeing several posts figured out what you actually meant and marked remaining as spam.