# User is putting up 5+ answers pointing to his own Github

Tags: discussion, spam

While working the "late answers" queue I came across a user who put a whole series of answers like this one:

> Here is the solution.
>
> https://github.com/amanjain325/angular-d3-charts/tree/master/src/app/stacked-bar-chart
>
> [View Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7084125/aman-jain)

The first one I just put up a "please don't just link" comment. Then I realized that he is doing this on scale.

Is that already SPAM?

And what is correct action? Go in and flag all the answers as SPAM? Or just flag as "bad content" and downvote/delete vote?

Comment: I believe it would fall under the Spam flag if you think it's on a large scale I'd raise a custom flag for a moderator to look into it explaining the situation and maybe linking a few of these cases. Even if it's not spam, as you've pointed out, link only answers aren't that good.

Comment: Just saw the same thing last night. I only downvoted one of the posts because it only had a link. Others were exactly the same as each other but at least provided an example of how to use the tool and can be applied to the questions where they were posted, so I left it as No Action Needed.

Comment: @tima No Action Needed was not the appropriate action IMO. As I understand it, the user is trying to use Stack Overflow to advertize their GitHub repository. This falls under ["overt self promotion"](https:///stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), which should be avoided. A custom flag, a comment, and/or editing out the link are appropriate actions. After having done this to one post, you could also choose "Skip" for the rest.

Comment: @S.L.Barth The user's post were still there today in the morning, but I think someone found the user after I posted this comment and removed all of the answers. It's good to know for the future, I'll flag the posts instead.

Comment: @tima Great! Hope I'm not stating the obvious, but just in case - a single custom mod flag, that explains the issue clearly, should be enough.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Technically, when you look at things from the gamification perspective (*I help with the quality of the site, while pimping my helpful-flags count*) ... one could think: "hmm, why not spam-flag all of the answers first, to then raise that one moderator flag"). Just saying.

Comment: @GhostCat Haha, true! I hope people will be careful with the spam flag though, as it has severe consequences for the poster. The NAA flag could work for the link-only answers, if one is after flag count and badges.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/3033053 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/300192

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would advise not posting user profile links on Meta... Witch hunts are common, sadly.

Back to the issue at hand: When you see repeated misbehaviour that *may* be caused by severe confusion or a misconception on what SO is about, the best course of action is to **raise a moderator flag**.

Moderators are generally more experienced on that kind of issue and have more tools to decide whether or not these are honest attempts at answering or just spam.

Commenting first was the right thing to do. Now, raise a moderator flag and let them handle the situation.

Comment: When you turn to that user profile ... you find the 5, 6 answers showing that problem ... gone. All deleted in the meantime. I will try to remember to not put up user links the next time.

Comment: I was sufficiently on the ball to catch it from seeing two flags in a row. But it does make our job easier if you pick one of the answers and raise a custom flag when you see an obvious pattern.