# Why was this answer marked as spam or rude/abusive?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, spam

Today I have found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55547286/7666442) was deleted by a mod as spam or rude/abusive.

Here is the content in that answer:

> You have forgot to name the array list name it some thing Just like this: ArrayList thelist

For below 10K user here is the screenshot of that answer:

[image]

I have checked the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55547286/revisions) the of that answer, and I didn't find any spam links or content in post that make that answer rude/abusive.

For below 10K user here is the screenshot for revisions history of that answer:

[image]

Now I'm curious why that answer is marked as spam or rude/abusive?

Comment: This was a fun one. The question asker is currently suspended, and there is now another deleted user/answer pair on the same question. That's all I can say. You can see the post timelines for more info.

Comment: @SamuelLiew You so easily could have omitted the _This was a fun one._ but you HAD to tease us...

Comment: _You can see the post timelines for more info:_ Hmm. Can you temporarily grant me 5013 rep, so that I can do so? I hate being excluded from fun...

Comment: *Can you temporarily grant me 5013 rep, so that I can do so? I hate being excluded from fun..*  @honk  check here [time-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwFFo.png)

Comment: Moderators are allowed to have fun? I thought it was all just back breaking labour ^^

Comment: @Draken what do you mean? Clicking buttons over and over again... I don't wish that on my worst enemy.

Comment: @Gimby - For sure. I mean, the heightened risk of spraining a finger from all the clicking alone :P

Comment: Could it be related to the answer just repeating an answer posted many days before? In other words - the answer is not adding anything new/useful but just a "bad" repeat of an "old" answer ==> spam?

Comment: @4386427: Please be aware, that on Stack Overflow spam is understood as [unsolicited commercial advertisement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/2675154).

Comment: @honk The delete reason says "spam or rude or abusive" As the answer obviously isn't rude or abusive it leaves only spam... but maybe none of the delete reasons applies in this case. Similar to the frequent examples of close reasons that doesn't match.

Comment: @4386427 that behavior can be flagged as abusive though, abusive to the system (not users)

Comment: While it's not relevant to a mod one-shot flag (like this one), be aware that you can edit a spam/rude post during the grace period so that you get posts like this, [so it looks like it was flagged out for no apparent reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307637/end-the-edit-grace-period-upon-two-or-more-spam-rude-flags-being-raised)