# Why am I still answer banned?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, spam, post-ban

I tried providing genuine answers on Stack Overflow, but I am still answer banned. I wrote two answers yesterday without any link to my product, but I am still answer banned. I spent enough time to write the answer; my time was wasted. I have lost hope on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I dont care whether you guys downvote or block me, because I got used to it. Why am I denied to make answers on stackoverflow? I want to know exact reason. If you guys always say the system will automatically remove the ban. How? When? Who is the system here?

Comment: How to make positive contributions? I made two answers yesterday without any link to my product, but still I'm blocked. I spent enough time to write the answer, its wasted.

Comment: Now I think I know what might be happening.  Did you previously provide answers that linked to "your product"?

Comment: Hey there John. The world isn't against you. If your answers are continually being blocked, it is because something is wrong in the way you approach answering questions. I'm grateful that you're taking the time to answer and I encourage you to not give up and instead, take a hard, critical look at how you answer compared to other, successful answers while also reading the abundance of linked material that people have posted here. Good luck.  PS. "I made two answers yesterday without any link to my product" That... that sounds suspicious.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your approach. Hmm, I'm not fine with this. I've answered with proper context only, but dont know why it happened. I'll try for other questions in future. If the system still blocks me, I have no idea but to delete the account. Thats it.

Comment: The site aggressively protects itself against spam, including answers with spammy self-promotion links to poster's sites. Did your previous answers contain such links (you've not replied to my previous query)? If so, the site will aggressively block you in an effort to protect itself.

Comment: @JohnSundarraj If you want to "lose your hope on stackoverflow" and give up...... Then leaving is probably the easiest. Posting this showcases you kinda want to get the feedback as to why it happened and improve. If that is the case... maybe you wanna change your tone? Because it sounds like you're blaming everyone, and aren't willing to maybe look at your contributions... and that won't get you anywhere...

Answer (score 48):

You are banned from posting new answers because two of them were flagged as spam by multiple users. This ban is automatically applied when it has reached a certain number of spam flags, and the post is then deleted.

As you can see, these two answers are considered spam by the community, as they contain excessive amounts of links to the same website, which generally suggests that you are affiliated to the website/service. Linking to something you're affiliated with (e.g. a product or website) without disclosing it's yours is considered spam on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow.

Please read [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

---

Here are the two deleted answers for your reference:

### [One](//stackoverflow.com/a/55533693)

[image]

### [Two](//stackoverflow.com/a/55533285)

[image]

Comment: In the faq [help/answer-bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans): _"automatic bans never expire or "time out"."_, So peoples banned for span have no way to redeem themself? Is they a special way to appeal?

Comment: @xdtTransform they can flag for moderator attention or discuss on meta..

Comment: Oh he didn't just spam on SO either. In fact, he's lucky he still has an account after [this much spam](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/domains/35663)

Comment: Very lucky indeed, people have had their accounts summarily shredded for less.