# Spam flags disputed

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, disputed-flags

I recently flagged two posts of the same user as spam, which were nevertheless disputed and no post was deleted as a result.

I am perfectly aware that accusing someone for spamming is no joke and should not be taken lightheartedly, so I would kindly invite opinions here in order to be sure that a) I am not being unfair b) the flag details were not overlooked by reviewers & moderators. I have gone again through the canonical Meta posts on the subject, [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) and [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow)

Here is the situation:

- According to the subject user's SO profile **links**, they seem affiliated with a specific `company`, of which the main open source product is a specific `product`
- According to their profile Github link, they are frequent committers to the repo `github.com/company/product` and related repos of the same company (e.g. `company/product-server`, `company/product-api` etc), with more than 100 commits in the last 3 months alone.

The first flag I raised was for an answer to a legit-looking question about some Google Cloud service; the answer went like

> If you [do this then] you will get the result immediately.
>
> Otherwise there are open source packages like `product` which could be
>   highly parallel, they can probably deliver you results in seconds if
>   you setup them on a big cluster or a GPU server. A single GPU server
>   can process about 100 minutes of audio in a minute.

The second flag was for an answer in a classic recommendation request ("*Does anybody have some expertise or experience with different libraries? Which is the best for such a task?*):

> You can try `product`, [...]. It
>   supports [this & that] out of box and has flexibility to do things like
>   [this & that and] the library is much more accurate than `this other product`.

In both cases:

- the question was not *about* the `product` (i.e. there was no mention of `product` anywhere in the question or the tags)
- no affiliation of the user with the specific `product` or `company` was mentioned, not even implicitly (e.g. "*our* `product`").

Even after rereading the canonical Meta posts on spam, these still look like textbook spam examples to me (in the sense of unsolicited & undisclosed self-promotion); but as said, I don't want to be unfair, so I welcome opinions explaining why I may be wrong.

And this discussion is not purely academic; unbeknownst of course to the flag reviewers, I have unearthed at least a dozen similar answers by the same user, which seem to exist only to promote the specific `product`, without the `product` itself being mentioned in the questions text or tags.

I faced a similar situation some weeks ago, flagging ~ 15 posts from another single user as spam, and all of those flags were found helpful. Only difference seems to be that, in that other case, the user affiliation was made explicit in the text of their profile, while here it is somewhat hidden in their profile links. **If** I was not wrong in raising these flags, could this be an explanation for the flags dispute? And if so, should I raise a custom flag instead?

Or I am just wrong, this is no spam, and I should do nothing further?

**UPDATE** (May 19): Both posts are now deleted by a moderator, after raising new custom flags.

Comment: None of those examples look like spam to me if I don't have more context. If you feel there is a spam pattern by a user you better raise a custom mod flag and point out the pattern you see.

Comment: Are you sure those spam flags are disputed? Or do you mean declined? Both outcomes exist but I have no idea how to end-up with a disputed a spam flag.

Comment: @rene disputed indeed, not declined

Comment: turns out I have 22 disputed spam flags. Looks like on those posts the red-flag was removed. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61457177/please-help-me-out) I spam flagged that ended disputed.

Comment: @rene Moderators can clear spam flags, which marks them as disputed. See the FAQ linked at the top of this post.

Comment: Employees of a company do tend to answer questions about the software they write.  Whether it is okay for, say, Eric Lippert to do so, but not for somebody from a much smaller company, is kinda obvious to everybody.  Vote for the answer, not the person who posted it.  Easy peasy.

Comment: @HansPassant answering questions *about* one's own software is nothing but natural, expected, commendable, and highly encouraged; but this is not at all the situation discussed here. Easy peasy, even for someone like me, who doesn't know who Eric Lippert is.

Comment: @rene I guess a moderator can post an answer here, if so inspired, but here's a quote from one mod that came up in SOCVR a little while ago: *"Never seen a spam flag disputed? Yeah, mods will do that sometimes if they understand why you flagged the post and agree it needs to be deleted, but don't think that the spam penalty is appropriate."* (Full attribution *could* be added, but you'll probably work it out for yourself, somehow.)

Comment: @AdrianMole fair point, only that here no post was deleted (as I guess the moderators can subsequently do, especially if they agree, even when disputing the flag). Updated post to clarify this.

Comment: @desertnaut The quoted chatroom message was, to be fair, just a chatroom message. I'm sure there are other, similar circumstances where the handling moderator doesn't want either the flagger or the poster penalized - which seems likely in your case.

Comment: I've also heard 'rumours' that "disputed" spam flags are something of a rarity; *collectibles*, even! (I have two.)

Comment: @AdrianMole seems likely indeed, especially if we count that the user affiliation was neither directly apparent nor in any case communicated in the flag. And yeah, now I have two of these, too! :)

Comment: Could be new badges: 50 disputed spam flags earns the "Spammer in the Works" silver badge; can't think of a suitable name for the gold version (at 500). Maybe "The **Rene**gade?"

Comment: @AdrianMole rumours seem to be wrong, currently I've got 111 disputed spam flags, I just checked

Answer (score 12):

Ultimately, yes, these posts by the user technically qualify as spam under our strict definition of spam which requires disclosure when affiliated with what you are linking (assuming I've correctly identified the user and posts). However, flagging these posts as spam is really not the best course of action, IMO.

### Better: Leave a comment reminding the user about the disclosure requirement

This user has >20k reputation and more than 1,100 posts on Stack Overflow. Of those, 24 posts link to this GitHub repository, with some moderately recent edits to old answers to add a link. That's not the profile of someone who is here, or who has been here, primarily to promote their stuff. It is consistent with someone who's put a lot of work into a project and found it relevant to questions they answer, previously answered, or even that they are selecting to answer some questions where it's relevant (but that's not all they are answering). In other words, the issue here appears that the user is just not disclosing affiliation in otherwise good posts.

IMO, that makes the goal here to educate the user about the disclosure requirement and get them to start adding disclosure into the posts they create which link to the repository.

What I prefer to do is leave a comment to the user reminding them that there's a requirement for disclosure of affiliation. In this case, the comment I'd probably use is:

> It appears you're affiliated with the GitHub repository linked here. When linking to something you're affiliated with, you *must disclose that affiliation in your post*. Without affiliation disclosure, it's technically considered spam. Please see: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's something like this, disclosure can just be something like "…, a repository I contribute to", etc. Please [edit] your post(s) to include disclosure.

I'll then schedule a revisit to the post in a couple/few days (following the post may also help, as you'll be notified of edits). If the user doesn't edit in that time, and has visited the site, then I'll consider more significant responses. If they haven't visited the site, I'll probably just wait a few more days. The more significant response can be anything from just editing disclosure into their posts (this all assumes the posts are good content, which here they generally appear to be), to raising a custom moderator flag where I explain the situation, including linking to where I commented and a link to a search showing the affected posts.

### If not willing to comment, raise a custom mod-flag, not a spam flag

If I didn't want to take the responsibility for leaving such a comment, then I'd raise a custom mod-flag and, again, explain. However, my experience is that *most* people who are here to actually participate in Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange react well to just being *politely* reminded about the requirement, and *asked* to add disclosure.

Basically, the options available to a moderator when handling a spam flag are quite limited. They also get limited information, other than that someone thinks the post is spam. IMO, spam flags really should be reserved for things that are *clearly* spam, as there's really not room for nuance in response to them, and they have significant penalties when upheld.

Raising a spam flag in this type of situation also requires the moderator to duplicate all the research which you've already done, happen to find the same things you found, *and* it requires that the moderator realizes that such research is necessary on this particular post. Just raising a spam flag here opens up a significant possibility of not properly communicating the problem to the moderator, has a significant risk of having the flag declined, and makes more work for our moderators, much of which wouldn't be necessary if you communicate the results of the effort you've already made. The only way to communicate that information privately to moderators is to raise a custom mod-flag.

### "Disputed" is a reasonable response to spam flags in this situation

The post is, under the definitions used on Stack Exchange, spam due to undisclosed affiliation (it says so right in the flag dialog, and elsewhere). Thus, "declined" is not appropriate. Imposing the -100 reputation penalty, and everything that goes along with a sustained spam flag, is inappropriate, so "helpful" isn't really the right response. That leaves "disputed", as the other available response.

I don't know if the moderator reached out to the user and tried to educate them about the requirement, but I'd consider that appropriate. What other action the moderator may, or may not have taken is not, however, something they should communicate to you.

Comment: Thank you. The 2nd part of your answer makes much sense indeed. However, re the 1st part, it sounds dangerously close to suggesting *selective application of the site rules*, which, I regret to say, is out of discussion as a matter of principle. We explicitly expect new users (and rightfully so) to have gone through the help system first, how can we expect otherwise from our experienced ones?

Comment: Plus, we have enough burden already trying to educate honest new users, and, at least personally, I don't think I have any obligation to do so for a 21K rep one, engaging in *personal* discussions in the comments which, however polite we may all try to be, have all reasons to go really south, with nasty consequences.

Comment: As said, I have already found many answers by the said user (including one-liners) that exist only as promotions, including a recent one-liner where, when the poor OP complains that the `product` is Linux-only, while they work in Windows, said user answers "*Windows will be supported soon, try Linux meanwhile*". I'm all in for good faith and so, but... *try Linux meanwhile*? Really? Sorry...

Comment: Anyway, thanks again for the answer; it should be obvious that I am in no kind of a vendetta or crusade here; since the issue is sufficiently surfaced (I did raise a couple more custom flags, as per your suggestion), I can leave it here and move on... Moderators can take it from here and do what they think is right, which, as you correctly point out, is none of my business to know in any detail whatsoever.

Comment: That said, and since you have obviously now witnessed this behavior yourself, you are very welcome of course to apply your 1st suggested approach yourself! You may even manage to persuade the said user to change his ways before my own flags get processed. Modifying slightly your recommended approach, I will "*schedule a revisit to the posts in a couple/few days*" to see how this goes :)

Comment: @desertnaut "I don't think I have any obligation to do so for a 21K rep one" - you don't indeed have any obligations... but think about educating someone who can later educate more people vs. educating ten "new users" that will most likely ignore any comments that are not directly giving the answer... Like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397544/why-was-a-flag-related-to-not-english-content-declined#comment770755_397545) where diamond mod was pointed to site rules.

Comment: Yes, with a user which has more than 1 rep, I tend to just delete the post instead of flagging as spam. Spammers are other kind of animals: creating an account just to promote their service, often completely unrelated to programming or computers. For legit users I only flag as spam/rude when the contents is clearly abusive, so even 10k+ users don't see it unless they absolutely want to.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre in the previous self-promotion case I refer to at the end of the post (it was a ~ 700 rep user), I had flagged the first post as NAA (it was a link-only answer); it was the moderator who handled the flag who switched it to a spam one, which I understandably considered as a clear guideline for similar cases. Speaking about educating users, I guess you'll agree that we shouldn't get such opposing signals for seemingly similar cases. I understand what you say here, but doesn't sound as a guideline for the subject case.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and there is always the issue with selective rules application I have already hinted at in my first comment here; at the end of the day, we are supposed to flag posts, not users. If you moderators see any larger pattern at the user level and decide to take further actions or not, it is not any of our (flaggers) business.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov indeed "obligation" was the wrong term here. The rest I guess is highly subjective: I have found that an astonishingly large (given their sheer number) amount of ~ 10% of new users I try to educate in the comments eventually conform to the site rules. And as much as I appreciate Makyen's thorough answer here, I am kind of disappointed that I still cannot see any educational effort from their part in any of the dozen or so self-promotional mostly link-only answers of the subject user (provided that we do talk for the same user indeed); we agree that this is not "my" case, right?