# Why was a flag related to not English content declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags, english

I have flagged recently [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798504) as not English content. But the flag was declined.

[image]

Could somebody explain why?

Comment: The post is in Spanish. I suggested an edit that translates to English and commented in Spanish directing them to https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur Please do not translate to English. See [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/215552)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was declined because you don't need a moderator to deal with it. You can do one or more of the following actions:

- You should not translate the post, especially if you'd have to rely on machine translations as they can have errors and if you're not fluent you won't spot them.
- Leave a comment explaining that Stack Overflow requires posts to be in English.
- Direct them to Stack Overflow in Spanish/Portuguese/Russian if appropriate.
- If you have more than 3,000 reputation vote to close as "Needs details or clarity".
- If you have less than 3,000 reputation flag with the "Needs details or clarity" option - this will put the question on the close queue where it can be closed.

None of these require a diamond moderator to intervene. Moderators won't usually migrate questions in Spanish/Portuguese/Russian to the appropriate site because, in general, we are not fluent in these languages so we can't judge the quality of the post. We only want to migrate good quality posts.

Comment: The post is in Spanish. I suggested an edit that translates to English and commented in Spanish directing them to https://es.stackoverflow.com/