# Why is my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, spam, specific-answer

Why is my answer deleted? [Are there TwinCAT 3 code formatter tools for structured text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201602/are-there-twincat-3-code-formatter-tools-for-structured-text/65961296#65961296)

Comment: the whole question is off-topic and should be closed (and later deleted)

Comment: I agree the question is off topic and should be closed (I have voted to do so as well), however, I do think the reason the answer was deleted is **not** correct. It *isn't* spam because you do say you are the author in the answer. *"Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)."* is not true because you do disclose your affiliation. Unless you have made this post in many locations and only citing one?

Comment: @Larnu so an answer like „Visit cheapdrugs.org. I’m its author“ isn’t spam because I have disclosed my affiliation?

Comment: @ead: it *is* a whole lot better than if one *didn't* disclose affiliation, that is for sure

Comment: @ead Spam is specifically defined, as I quoted above. The above is not "spam" by [so]'s definition, because the OP discloses their definition.

Comment: It's spam if you don't disclose your affiliation. That doesn't mean it cannot be spam if you do.

Comment: @Larnu it would fall foul of the "some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website" as they only had one visible answer and that was about their site.

Comment: One answer with a disclosure doesn't equal spam, in my opinion @MartinSmith, even if that is the only answer the OP has ever made. Many answers, yes, but not one. I would suggest with the given answer, my opinion is the one of the mods too. If someone is mass posting problems, with disclosure, that is more warrant of a custom mod flag.

Comment: Can someone explain the benefit of the pile on downvotes on this meta question? What is the message that we are sending the OP? ...don't ask any honest questions on MSO? Talk about unwelcoming.  Not one comment informing the OP about how to ask the same question in a fashion that will not attract downvotes.  Do meta members just enjoy downvoting?  Is anyone else tired of this persistent meta trend?  This is not how you grow a community -- this is how you prevent new engagement and allow the grumpy few to completely control meta.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you..

Comment: @GerBar If I am honest, I would expect that the downvotes are because you "didn't show any research effort".  We don't know if you bothered to crack open any Help pages before asking.  This _would be_ reasonable justification for a downvote.  My issue is that not one person explained your question's pummelling.

Answer (score 21):

Your answer was deleted by a moderator in response to a spam flag, leaving the spam flag marked as "helpful". However, the situation fulfills all of:

1. You disclose your affiliation;
2. The question asks for resources similar to what you linked in your answer (or at least similar to how you describe the thing which you linked; In this case, I didn't actually check to verify what you linked); **and**
3. You have not posted an "excessive" number of posts about your "thing". What, exactly, "excessive" means in this context is not explicitly defined. I, personally, am not going to have a problem with a single post mentioning your "thing" in a reasonable manner on a question that's asking for such information. However, much beyond that single post will start to trigger our thinking that you are here *only* to promote your "thing". I'd note that we also pay attention to how you post and the *content* of your post(s). If it's a bunch of marketing, then we're going to be much quicker to think that you're here to promote. If it's a post that looks like one programmer telling another programmer how to achieve what they're asking about using some tool, then we're less likely to see it as spam.

Because your answer fulfills the above requirements, it is *not* spam, based on the [definition for spam which is used on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638). As such, I have disputed all spam flags on the answer, which also caused the answer to be undeleted.

However, the question is an off-topic request for external resources. It had already been closed. Overall, it did not appear that the question was worth keeping, so I deleted the question.

Comment: Somewhat notable, perhaps, is that it was a question of a programmer that wanted to format his code.  It happens, programmers don't usually spend the time to write their own.  This one did.

Comment: I honestly don''t get why it is deleted.
I think it's a fair question. OP is asking a good question, at that time there was not such tool available. 
There is one now and I think it's useful for other PLC programmers to know in case they are searching for it.

Comment: @GerBar - Are you objecting to the deletion of the question or the answer?  The question was definitely out of scope.

Comment: Deletion of the complete question: It has been there for months, It's a relevant question in the world of PLC programmers. I provide an answer to it, and suddenly it all has to be deleted. 
Why would it be out of scope?

Comment: @GerBar Tool requests are always off-topic. The fact that it's been there for months doesn't mean it's on-topic, it just means it escaped notice until now.