# How to handle having a flag declined for a now deleted answer

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, moderation

Several hours ago, I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411982/ios-tableview-delete-row-in-section/68469483#68469483) as not being an answer. Now I noticed that this flag has been declined due to "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it", but the actual answer has also been deleted.

Since you need 10.000 reputation to see deleted posts, what's next? I flagged an answer as NAA (which at the time I believed deserved that flag) yet it got declined, but I can't see (or remember) what the answer was or why it was eventually deleted.

Comment: There's nothing you really need to do, flags get declined, a single declined flag won't cause any problems

Comment: That answer still can be viewed as an "attempt to answer" and Stack Overflow is extremely lenient on what counts as an "attempt". That answer there has been deleted for being plagiarized, not because of NAA.

Comment: Like I said, don't fully remember the answer, but I'll remember that feedback.

Comment: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/11682469)

Comment: Another one to be careful of is spam. [It also has a very narrow definition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow). Plus the spammer typically gets nuked from orbit, so use it cautiously. If it's not blatantly obvious, you're better off raising a custom flag with a good description of the problem.

Comment: Tom more or less gave the answer. The post *looks* to be an answer. While it might seem obvious to folks versed in the language that it's not, that's not necessarily true for a mod who has no expertise in that language. The post was plagiarized so it was deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do anything other than learning from your mistakes.

Your mistake was flagging the answer using the Not An Answer flag, which is reserved for things that can't be considered an answer by any stretch. What you flagged was just a code dump. That code could have been an answer as far as mods are concerned. If you know for certain that this is not an answer to the question and should be deleted, then explain it clearly using the "in need of moderator's attention" option.

In any case, the outcome you wanted has been reached. The post is gone. Why dispute the action that you wanted all along? If you really need to dispute a moderator action then you can use any post and flag using the "in need of moderator's attention" option with a link to the deleted post. But your declined flag won't be changed to helpful, and you are only risking another declined flag for wasting moderators' time... so probably just leave it alone and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I flagged an answer as NAA.
At the time it said:

> DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE DELETE.

By the time it was reviewed, it looked like an answer.  I don't think I have used NAA  since.

It seems best to me to stay away from NAA flags.

Comment: That's a mistake, the flag should not have been declined. Please don't let a single incorrectly declined flag stop you from raising flags. NAA was an absolutely acceptable flag to raise on the revision that had only the vandalized content, and you should continue raising those.

Comment: For future reference, this would be a good answer to flag as VLQ, because that would be cleared by an edit.  However, such vandalized answers should generally be reverted, rather than deleted.

Comment: Yes, you did everything right there. Given that there was no earlier version of the answer recorded, it would have been impossible for you, or anyone other than the OP, to revert it to an earlier version. Presumably, the OP vandalized it very quickly after posting in the edit grace period. Unfortunately, the moderator who handled your flag declined it. I assume the moderator just didn't see the edit indicator. Those edit indicators are, unfortunately, not all that noticeable and use the same styling as the indicator that there were prior declined flags on the post.

Comment: Side note: If you find yourself with an answer that you've rethought, found wanting, and now want gone, there's a delete link below the question. You can edit and fix the answer while it is deleted and then undelete it once you're comfortable. Save you from smurfing over poor suckers like this and shields the answer from the barrage of downvotes it could get while vandalized.