# What should I do about further questions asked in the Answers section?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

I have just qualified for review queues and sometimes I do not know which option to choose. And I ask this question of the older ones: When the continuation of a question is asked in the answers section, should I flag it or does it look ok?

Comment: The answer section is for answering the question, nothing more and nothing less. If someone is attempting to ask a question or continue or clarify a question in that space, then that entry simply does not belong. End of story.

Comment: It definitely does not look OK. Related: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/2745495). See the section on "Asking for clarifications".

Comment: Can you [add](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/417955/edit) one or more examples?

Comment: Also keep an eye out for spam. SO has [a very tight definition of spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow), and that doesn't include folks asking the same question over and over or generally being annoying.