# Copying your own, attributed blog content

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I've just stumbled across [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71963103/5211833) where the OP linked to their own blog with attribution, but all contents within the answer have been copied from said blog, without additional information added. According to [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)  from the help centre:

> Do *not* copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.

This piece isn't clear in this particular situation though, because it is original content by the author, just published before in another place<sup>1</sup>. Given the other contributions by this user are good and not overly often linking to their own blog, spam flagging seems harsh.

I've seen [What is the policy for linking to your own blog in your answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254280/5211833) and [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/325771) too, however, these do not seem to cover this case.

How to deal with this case, where the OP copy-pastes part of their own blog post attributes it, but doesn't add any new content?

<sup>1: Self-plagiarism isn't a thing, at least according to Dutch judges, since you cannot copy your own content without giving, however implicit, permission to yourself to copy said content</sup>

Comment: Given that even attribution is not required when copying one's own content that is previously published elsewhere [ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333708), I don't see how block-quoting can be required.

Comment: I, personally, think that the main issue isn't that it's not cited, but that the answer contains no *original* content. The fact that the poster *owns* the copyright of the content is irrelevant, in my view.

Comment: @Larnu By "original" do you mean "bespoke", i.e. brand new content that is written specifically for the answer? That's not what "original" means in the "How not to plagiarize" guidance, there it just means "one's own work".

Comment: What Larnu says. It seems pretty clear to me, thou shalt not copy wholesale. There are no exceptions, no corner cases, no ifs ands or buts. I get it though, I'm Dutch too. Simple rules are illegal according to our bureaucratic DNA ;)

Comment: Do you have a citation for that intention, @cigien . As I read it, the content is entirely quoted (from the user in question's blog), and so the content isn't original in terms of the content on [so] (regardless of if it's catered for the answer or not). The fact the content is not catered for the question posted on [so] is a different problem.

Comment: @Larnu The citation is in the link in my first comment. It's "only" a meta consensus, not a definition lifted from the help-center if that's you mean.

Comment: Related: *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)* - e.g., *"...simply tacking a "Reference" link at...a wall of unquoted text...does not count as proper attribution"*

Comment: @cigien that answer to me says that citation isn't required, not that the answer cannot be **entirely** copied.

Comment: @Larnu That answer says "This includes reusing an answer you posted to ...". The "reusing" reads to me like the entire answer could be copied, and that would be fine. By any chance, do you have some citation/reference for the claim that "original", and "entirely copied content" apply to one's own content, or is that just your understanding of the rules, or how you feel they should be?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the case for that particular blog post, but the *majority* of blog posts on [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)) being copied to Stack Overflow are already plagiarised (often 100% copied from some older blog posts somewhere else outside of Medium). There are similar problems with other platforms that don't take plagiarism seriously, like [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) and [DEV](https://dev.to/about).

Comment: As I said, it's my interpretation, @cigien .

Comment: The answer says "check out my blog entry for details", but I'm not seeing what extra, in-depth information the blog is providing. It's not like the answer is just the relevant excerpts from a much, much longer blog post; the answer _is_ the blog post just with the introduction and a couple tidbits removed. A simple "From my blog..." link at the bottom would have been better than, essentially, "Be sure to click through to claim the additional 2% of information I've withheld."  I don't think such promotion warrants any consequences worse than leaving a bad taste in the reader's mouth, though.

Comment: Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-can-i-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-os-x-v10-10-yo/66221264#comment130675294_66221264) of such a plagiarised blog post on Medium. It is fairly typical of the plagiarism going on on Medium.

Comment: Plagiarism is more rampant than we realise, I think, including internally on Stack Overflow. Any late answer with complete English sentences is suspect. I don't particularly look out for them, but here is [an example from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800482/when-and-why-to-use-malloc/65674880#65674880).

Comment: A first for me: [A question where ***all*** answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72079389/what-is-the-package-json-file#comment132255838_72079389) (3) are the result of blatant plagiarism!!!!! (Wholesale copying - not a single word of their own. Answer IDs 72151136, 72155588, and 72161868.) Again, I don't particularly look out for them, so there must many many more out there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Copying your own work is not plagiarism on Stack Exchange

Stack Exchange isn't an academic research journal where you're expected to be presenting novel, not-published-elsewhere ideas in each submission.  Our [referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) are all about referencing material *written by others*.

Nor do we require any exclusive rights to your content—posting it here doesn't mean you can't post it elsewhere, too, as you retain full rights to it. In fact, given that you can post it elsewhere, it'd be a bit silly if we enforced the requirements only if you posted it on the blog before posting it on Stack Exchange, or to go back and edit it (or change the blog post?) if you later post it on your blog.

A few words of advice to people who want to re-use content from their blog:

- It's probably a good idea to indicate, somehow, that you're the same person who wrote the blog, so that people don't think it's plagiarism and flag it for removal.  Attributing the blog post is an easy way to do that, especially if it's not obvious that you're the author.
- Be careful to follow our self-promotion rules.  Make sure it's clear that it's *your* blog, and you shouldn't be linking it in the vast majority of your answers.
- Make sure the answer is tailored to the question.  It's unlikely (but possible) that an already-written blog post answers the question *verbatim* (unless, of course, you're writing the answer with an eye toward *also* posting it on your blog—but still make sure that it's tailored to the question).

Comment: In this case, the blog shows the same creation date. It looks as if they wrote an extended answer, decided to post that as a blog and paraphrased the code-bits to SO. They did that only once though (on non-deleted posts).

Comment: @Adriaan - I don't see anything wrong in that, provided they're meeting the requirements of the bullet points in Ryan's answer (particularly the second and third).